# Numbers with units with VoiceOver

Tags: ios, voiceover

I've got a field on an iPhone app that contains "1.2 m". VoiceOver will speak this as "1 point 2 metres". I was a little surprised that VoiceOver was smart enough to understand units.

However, I have a different field that contains the text "1.2 m/s" which VoiceOver speaks as "1 point 2 metres slash S", which obviously isn't what I want. Another slight oddity is that in the Google Earth app, the longitude and latitude are pronounced as "xx degrees, xx minutes, xx inches" which is clearly wrong.

This raises a couple of questions for me:

1. What units does iOS VoiceOver understand?
2. Do I have any control over what VoiceOver says without setting the text explicitly in the accessibilityLabel? Can I tell it to understand that "m/s" is pronounced "metres per second"?

Comment: You can always set the accessibility label on the text field yourself. Then you can have a custom string such as "One point two meters per second".

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yes, I know I can set the label myself, but if iOS will do it automatically then it's less work for me. Trying to find out what iOS does actually do. Can't find any documentation.

Comment: Interestingly, OSX VoiceOver correctly pronounces "1 m/s" as "one meter per second". I'm quite interested to see if someone knows of a way to do what you're asking. But pragmatically, especially if this pronunciation is a fundamental part of your app, then you probably should explicitly set the `accessibilityLabel`.

Comment: Related: VoiceOver on iOS 8.1 reads "1.05" as "One dot zero five", and "1.23" as "One dot twenty three". Not ideal.  "One point zero five" and "One point two three" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, to be honest, I don't know the metrics perfectly handled by VoiceOver but I always make tests to be sure of what's vocalized : the best way to be 100% sure in my view.

About your second one, I always format the date, time and numbers I use in my labels so as not to have unpleasant surprise with a new iOS release that could weirdly interprets these elements: I follow [these steps](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#date-time-and-numbers) to format these data.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that people who depend on VoiceOver and use it every day to access information are familiar with its quirks and expect to hear information read out in a consistent way. Any efforts to work around those quirks might create an experience that is actually more confusing. That said, if your intended reader is unfamiliar with the units/numbers expressed, then a parenthetical clarification of any abbreviations will be of benefit to all users (not just those using VoiceOver).